# How to find constant $a$ and real function $f$ such that: $\Im f(a+ix)=\ln(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, even-and-odd-functions

I have a question. Given a real function $g(x)$, is it possible to find some constant $a$ and a real function $f$ such that

$$\Im f(a+ix)=g(x)$$ For example,

$$f(x)=e^x,~~~~\Im f(ix)=\Im e^{ix}=\sin x=g(x)$$

and

$$f(x)=\ln(1+x),~~~\Im f(ix)=\arctan x=g(x)$$

It seems this works because $\sin x$ and $\arctan x$ are odd functions, but I can't rigorously prove it.

If $g(x)$ is not an odd function, for example, $g(x)=\ln x$, is it possible to find a constant $a$ and a real function $f$ such that

$$\Im f(a+ix)=\ln x$$

Comment: "*a real function $f$*" $\;-\;$ The function $f$ you describe has a complex argument and takes complex values. What is "*real function*" supposed to mean, then?

Comment: I mean if $x$ is real, then $f(x)$ is real.

Comment: You should edit the question and clarify that, because that's not what a real function is. A real function is a function with domain $\mathbb R$, and a real-valued function is a function with codomain $\mathbb R$. Your $f$ is neither.

Comment: You can just take $f(z)\,=\,h(z)+i\,g(\operatorname{Im}(z))$ where $h$ is an arbitrary real-valued complex function. The additional condition $f(\mathbb R) \subseteq \mathbb R$ is equivalent to $g(0)=0$.